# How do I record my voice and make it a file in java?

Tags: java, file, audio, audio-streaming, microphone

I'm trying this code, but after test 5 and test 9, the code seems to stop functioning at `audioStream.write()`.

Nothing after

```
AudioSystem.write(audioStream, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, audioFile);
```

is executed by the program. How do I fix this or is there another way to record my voice?

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Mic{



    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Sound test starting");

        try {
            AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 44100, 16, 2, 4, 44100, false);

            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
            if(!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info))
            {
                System.err.println("Line is not supported");
            }

            final TargetDataLine targetLine = (TargetDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(info); 
            targetLine.open();

            System.out.println("Recording voice");
            targetLine.start();

            Thread thread = new Thread();

            {
                //@Override public void run();

                {

                    AudioInputStream audioStream = new AudioInputStream(targetLine);
                    File audioFile = new File("Recording.wav");
                    System.out.println("test5");
                    try { System.out.println("test9");
                        AudioSystem.write(audioStream, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, audioFile);
                        System.out.println("audio writing test");
                    }

                    catch(IOException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println("test6");
                    System.out.println("Recording Stopped");

                }
            };
            thread.start();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            targetLine.stop();
            targetLine.close();

            System.out.println("Ended sound test");
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ie){
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(LineUnavailableException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



}
```

Comment: If you compile and run, " System.out.println("audio writing test");" is never executed, but the print tests "test5" and "Test9" are executed. What did I do wrong with the audiosystem.write method?

Comment: Does ``audioFile.canWrite()`` return ``true``?

Comment: this is what happens when i run the code. http://gyazo.com/8d5d2db0f061d30cac0411b17ccab3c1

Comment: @PatrickRoberts yes it returns true

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you're doing something that's not thread-safe.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts do you know how to edit my code to make it thread safe?

Comment: No, sorry. It was only a guess, given that a lot of Java issues arise from thread safety. I cannot say for sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible things that could be happening:

- The `write` call could be blocking for ever.
- The `write` call could be throwing some unchecked exception, that is going unreported.

Temporarily change this:

```
    catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

to this:

```
    catch (Throwable e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and show us the stacktrace (if any) that now gets output.

---

Here's another couple of possibility:

The `write` operation you are calling is actually a copy from `audioStream` to the file:

- If the source (`audioStream`) is not properly set up, the `write` could actually be blocked in reading data from your input device.
- Have you checked the output file?  Has anything been written to it?  It could be that the recording process is working ...

Either way, the next thing I would do would be to run this under a debugger, and try to figure out what the `write` call is doing while it is (apparently) blocked.

Comment: http://gyazo.com/36a9edec772ce76a47b6b8727041cf03 this is a screenshot of running the code before and after changing the catch error. both cases the program just runs forever and i have to force quit it. do you have any idea as to why the write call is blocking forever?